# Solve Lyapunov-like equation $AX + XA = B$ for antisymmetric $X$, with antisymmetric $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the usual Lyapunov case, B is symmetric, but in my case, X and B are antisymmetric. A is still symmetric, though. There probably isn't a simple analytic solution, so I'm trying to find out if it can be solved uniquely. With my restrictions, there are n(n - 1)/2 equations and variables, so I am hopeful, but as for proving existence and uniqueness, I still have no idea where to start. If there were a general existence and uniqueness proof with A and B general and invertible, say, that would be all I would need.

If you're wondering how I cooked up such a problem, I ran into it when solving for the motion of a 3D rotating object with rotation matrix $A(t)$ using the Lagrangian $L = T = \frac 1 2 tr(\dot A J \dot A^T)$ and the constraint $A^T A = 1$. J is a symmetric matrix. (It is uniquely specified by, but not equal to the rotational inertia matrix I. $I = tr(J) - J$.)

When you solve for A using the Euler-Lagrange equation and Lagrange multipliers, you get the equation of motion $\ddot A J = A \lambda$, where $\lambda(t)$ is a symmetric matrix of Lagrange multipliers, which may take on any value you want, so long as it is symmetric.

Expressing A in terms of its own differential equation $\dot A = AX$, where X (antisymmetric) is in the $SO(3)$ Lie algebra, you eliminate A and $\lambda$ and end up with a differential equation for just X, and it looks like this:

$\dot X J + J \dot X = [J, X^2]$

It is very pretty, but I have no idea if it's right, so I've been testing for sanity, the first step of which is of course existence and uniqueness. If I can isolate $\dot X$, I know right away that it's fine in that respect because it just fits the form of the classic dynamical system.

So, what do you think?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: I came up with my own solution that works in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I exploited the fact that there is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the $SO(3)$ Lie algebra, $X = \vec L . \omega$, and turned the whole thing into a vector equation for $\omega$. Here's my general solution:

$X = \vec L . \omega$ where $\omega = \frac 1 2 (A - tr(A))^{-1} . tr(\vec L B)$

When I substituted my values for $X$, $A$, and $B$, I was *amazed* to see Euler's equation appear:

$\dot \omega = - I^{-1} (\omega \times I \omega)$

So, from Lagrangian mechanics, I managed to recover Euler's equation!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Sankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalised, that is, $A=QDQ^T$ for some orthogonal $Q$ and $D=\mathrm{diag}(\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n)$ is diagonal. So $AX+XA=B$ is equivalent to $Q^T(QDQ^TX+XQDQ^T)Q=Q^TBQ$ and with $Y=Q^TXQ$, we get $DY+YD=C$, where $C=Q^TBQ$. It means that the $(i,j)$ entry of $Y$, $y_{ij}$, satisfies
$$\tag{1}
(\delta_i+\delta_j)y_{ij}=c_{ij},
$$
where $c_{ij}$ is the corresponding entry of $C$. It is clear from (1) that a unique solution exists when $A$ and $-A$ have no common eigenvalues.

To get an expression for $X$ in terms of $A$ and $B$, consider using the [Kronecker product and vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products). Since $AX+XA=B$ iff $\newcommand{\vc}{\mathrm{vec}}$ $\vc(AX)+\vc(XA)=\vc(B)$ we get using $\vc(UXV)=(V^T\otimes U)\vc{X}$ the equivalent system
$$
[(I\otimes A)+(A\otimes I)]\vc(X)=\vc(B).
$$

Comment: Yep, that definitely works. That's funny... Why didn't I think of diagonalising A. It is usually diagonal, anyway, since the object is usually defined such that its principle axes are aligned with those of the coordinate system...